# SQL Server Express 2012 - how to merge two cells permanently

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to merge 2 columns in my database permanently. How do I do this?

Comment: what are the datatypes ? What kind of "merge" ? Do you want, say "abc" and "def" to become "abcdef" ? And WHY do you want to do that ? I hope this is not for display purpose :D

Comment: Sorry. Its all NVARCHAR(255). The field contains more than 255 characters. So I think I need to merge them and put them into a new datatype

Comment: You can just concat the two columns by using an update statement :UPDATE table SET f1 = ISNULL(f1,'') + '' + ISNULL(f2, '')

Comment: Thats a good idea. But the 2nd problem is that the fields are 255 characters. I need to create a new field and dump the data and delete the existing columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should do the stuff :

```
ALTER TABLE table
ALTER COLUMN f1 NVARCHAR(4000)

UPDATE table SET f1 = ISNULL(f1,'') + '' + ISNULL(f2, '')

ALTER TABLE table
DROP COLUMN f2
```